# Error on import com.lowagie.database.DatabaseConnection

Tags: itext

I completed Chapter 1 exercises and moved now to Chapter 2.  I am on first "DatabaseTest" expercise and I am getting error on import statements:

```
import com.lowagie.database.DatabaseConnection;
```

and

```
import com.lowagie.database.HsqldbConnection;
```

I downloaded the jar files from "http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/".

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong and if I need some additional files?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the Lowagie who wrote these examples. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but let me explain what I do. With every release, I check out all examples and jars from SVN on the iText server, copy the new iText.jar to the `lib` directory, and I run `ant execute`. (I don't do this manually, I have a shell script that does this for me.) ANT uses the `build.xml` in the root of the book directory, which in turn uses the `examples.xml`. These scripts automatically build all PDFs that you can find on the iText site. This works every time (if it doesn't, I'm in trouble). Maybe you can start like this, and then try to isolate what is different with what you do.