# Where is the com.lowagie.database class?

Tags: itext

I could not find the com.lowagie.database.DatabaseConnection and com.lowagie.database.HsqldbConnection in the itext-5.5.5.jar. 
Thus I could not do the exercises in the book titled itext In Action. Does anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the classes [here](http://examples.itextpdf.com/src/com/lowagie/database/DatabaseConnection.java) and [here](http://examples.itextpdf.com/src/com/lowagie/database/HsqldbConnection.java).

Which version of the book do you own? If you own the the [first edition](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/) there was an update ([second edition](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/)) released. In 2009 there was a bigger change to the iText library which also renamed the package from com.lowagie to com.itextpdf.

And as I just saw you may also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184155/error-on-import-com-lowagie-database-databaseconnection).

The iText projects recently moved from SourceForge to Github. You can find all the code related to the second edition here: https://github.com/itext/book

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *The iText projects recently moved from SourceForge to Github* - oops, I missed that. I merely was quite surprised that there were no recent check-ins anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. My book is the second edition. According to my experience, I think the most convenient way to get the material needed for book's exercises is to go to the publisher website (www.Manning.com/lowagie2/) to download the source code (the big file 26MB).